# Sort Ids that are only numbers in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an JSON file with data inside of an user

```
[
 {
"_id": "62bd5fba34a8f1c90303055c",
"index": 0,
"email": "mcdonaldholden@xerex.com",
"nameList": [
  {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Wendi Mooney"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Holloway Whitehead"
  }
  ]
  },
  {
"_id": "62bd5fbac3e5a4fca5e85e81",
"index": 1,
"nameList": [
  {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Janine Barrett"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Odonnell Savage"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Patty Owen"
  }
  ]
 },
 {
"_id": "62bd5fbaf8f417d849c135db",
"index": 2,
"email": "pattyowen@xerex.com",
"nameList": [
  {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Earline Goff"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Glenna Lawrence"
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "name": "Bettye Sawyer"
  }
]
```

I had to sort every user by : if user has more than two names
if user ids are consecutive
and if user ids are numbers

I managed to sort user by more than two names and if ids are consecutive

```
userData.filter(({nameList}) => 
nameList.length > 2 &&
!nameList.some(({id}, index, array) => index && array[index - 1].id !== id - 1)
);
```

In the case that an object has an id as number I should not return the objects. How can I implement that in my code?

The output is expected to be all the arrays that meet the filter, and some() criteria. Which is if objects has more than 2 names, its ids are consecutive and the ids should be a number.

Comment: Could you add the desired output to your question?

Comment: Oh, I need to return all the objects that meet the criteria : Has more than two names in the nameList object, Its ids are consectutive, and ids are numbers. I made the code for the first two, cant seem to make the third

Comment: For your given input data, could you please update the question with the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if the `id` is of *type* number:

```
(typeof id == "number")
```

To check if can be cast to a number

```
(id == parseInt(id, 10))
```

The complete code then (you were close):

```js
var userData = get_data();

userData = userData.filter(function(item) {

  return item.nameList.length > 2 &&
    item.nameList.every(function(item, index, arr) {
      return parseInt(item.id) == item.id && (index == 0 || item.id - arr[index - 1].id == 1)
    })

})


console.log(userData);

function get_data() {
  return [{
      "_id": "62bd5fba34a8f1c90303055c",
      "index": 0,
      "email": "mcdonaldholden@xerex.com",
      "nameList": [{
          "id": 0,
          "name": "Wendi Mooney"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Holloway Whitehead"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": "62bd5fbac3e5a4fca5e85e81",
      "index": 1,
      "nameList": [{
          "id": 0,
          "name": "Janine Barrett"
        },
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Odonnell Savage"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Patty Owen"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": "62bd5fbaf8f417d849c135db",
      "index": 2,
      "email": "pattyowen@xerex.com",
      "nameList": [{
          "id": 0,
          "name": "Earline Goff"
        },
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Glenna Lawrence"
        },
        {
          "id": 7,
          "name": "Bettye Sawyer"
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important
}
```